# How to change deselected objects color in edit mode at blender 2.9 series?

Tags: edit-mode

In blender 2.9 series when enter in edit mode other objects getting darken!

[image]

While in blender versions older than 2.9 and also in version 3.0.0, selected and deselected objects have same color in edit mode:

[image]

How to change deselected objects color in edit mode at blender 2.9 series same as older versions and newer versions (3 series)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how to adjust the colour of the inactive object in edit mode, but I do know how to control the fading level of the object. It`s very simple just tab into **edit mode**, go to the **'overlays'**, check **'fade inactive geometry'** box and then change the value to whatever you want

[image]